# I dont send json data with axios in reactjs but postman is work

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

I want to send the JSON data to other computer web API server. I can't send data with Axios in Reactjs but Postman is working. These computers work on the same network.

---

> ERROR in console;
>
> OPTIONS https://192.168.1.214:5001/api/books 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://192.168.1.214:5001/api/books'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
>       at createError (createError.js:17)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:80)

---

Error image : https://i.resimyukle.xyz/830y7z.png

```
addAnswers = async (dispatch, e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const newItem = {
            "bookName" : "information",
            "price" : "11.11",
            "category" :"information",
            "author" : "yazar"
        }
        const response = await axios.post("https://192.168.1.214:5001/api/books",newItem);
        console.log(response);
```

Comment: You can check the duplicate question. If you don't have any access to the API server then you have a few options here. You can look at the proxy option for create-react-app.

Answer (score -2):

You have to do like this

```
   let getRresponse;

   axios.post("https://192.168.1.214:5001/api/books",newItem)
    .then((response) => {
      getRresponse = response;       //get your response here like this
    });

    console.log(getRresponse);
```

Enjoy !

Comment: This code not solved my problem

Comment: @ahmetcamli this one is the standard structure of axios, if code was not working in your , then you do mistake somewhere else.

Comment: @vijaysadhu, OP is using an async function and handling it properly with async/await. `axios` provides a promise, there isn't any standard structure handling for this.

Comment: hey @devserkan why you still use async-await ,
there is no need to use them.

Comment: What do you mean by "no need"? It is a new addition with ES2017. [Please read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description).

Comment: hey @devserkan here you have misunderstanding ,i'm taking like, if you use my code, then you don't need to use async/await , and thanks man for doing R&D for me to give me this awesome doc.

Comment: @vijaysadhu, We can use async/await easily here. OP does that and it is fine. async/await is newer then promises (we can use them mutually, not a replacement of course). Unfortunately, this isn't related with the real problem here.